# Arcpy script suddenly stops

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I have a script that's copying files from 2 geodatabases in separate locations into a existing geodatabase on my C:\ Drive. The first part of the script runs workspace3 code perfectly. For some reason the script stops and closes before copying data from workspace4. Am I missing some piece of code that allows it to flow to the next section?

```
# Import modules
import arcpy, os, string, sys
# Set NEO environment settings
workspace3 = "M:/EIS_DRAFTS/EIS_LAN/Lancaster_UPDM.gdb"
workspace4 = "M:/EIS_DRAFTS/EIS_ORW/Orwell SHP Files/ORWELL UPDM.gdb"

##########################################################################
############################ Workspace3 ##################################
##########################################################################

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace3

# Dataset
in_dataset_P_NEO = ['MainComponents','ServiceComponents']

# Dataset
in_dataset_P_PipeSystem = ['P_MeterSetting','P_Pipes',
'P_Service']

#Not included inside a Dataset
in_dataset_P_EverythingElse = ['P_PipelineMarker']

out_dataset_P_NEO = 'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Lancaster.gdb/P_NEO'
out_dataset_P_Integrity = 'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Lancaster.gdb/P_Integrity'
out_dataset_P_PipeSystem = 'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Lancaster.gdb/P_PipeSystem'
out_dataset_P_EverythingElse =     
'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Lancaster.gdb/P_EverythingElse'

# Execute .Exists & .Delete_management
if arcpy.Exists(out_dataset_P_NEO):
arcpy.Delete_management(out_dataset_P_NEO)
if arcpy.Exists(out_dataset_P_PipeSystem):
arcpy.Delete_management(out_dataset_P_PipeSystem)
if arcpy.Exists(out_dataset_P_EverythingElse):
arcpy.Delete_management(out_dataset_P_EverythingElse)


Create_dataset_P_NEO = 'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Lancaster.gdb'
out_name_P_NEO = "P_NEO"

Create_dataset_P_Integrity = 'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Lancaster.gdb'

out_name_P_PipeSystem = "P_PipeSystem"

out_name_P_EverythingElse = "P_EverythingElse"

sr = arcpy.SpatialReference("NAD 1983 UTM Zone 11N")

# Execute .CreateFeaturedataset
arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(Create_dataset_P_NEO, 
out_name_P_NEO,sr)
arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(Create_dataset_P_Integrity,     
out_name_P_PipeSystem,sr)
arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(Create_dataset_P_Integrity,     
out_name_P_EverythingElse,sr)

arcpy.env.outputMFlag = "Disabled"
arcpy.env.outputZFlag = "Disabled"

# Execute .FeatureClassToGeodatabase
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(in_dataset_P_NEO, 
out_dataset_P_NEO)
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(in_dataset_P_PipeSystem,         
out_dataset_P_PipeSystem)
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(in_dataset_P_EverythingElse,     
out_dataset_P_EverythingElse)

print "Finished!"


# Open a log file to write to
#
f = open(r'C:\Lancaster Schedule.log','w')

# Write date/time
#
f.write(time.strftime('%x %X'))
f.write('\n')

# Test receiving of arguments/parameters via arcpy
#
f.write("Parameter 0 : " + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + "\n")

# Python info
#
f.write("Python EXE : " + sys.executable + "\n")
f.write("Architecture : " + platform.architecture()[0] + "\n")
f.write("Path to arcpy : " + imp.find_module("arcpy")[1] + "\n")
f.close()

##########################################################################
############################ Workspace4 ##################################
##########################################################################

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace4

# Set local variables
in_dataset_P_Orwell = ['ORWELL_COMPONENTS','ORWELL_FARM_TAPS',
'ORWELL_LINE_MARKERS',
'ORWELL_METERS',
'ORWELL_PIPE_SYSTEM',
'ORWELL_SERVICES',
'ORWELL_STATIONS']

#Dataset
in_dataset_P_Integrity = ['P_Anomaly']

#Dataset
in_dataset_P_PipeSystem = ['P_ExcessFlowValve',
'P_MeterSetting',
'P_NonControllableFitting',
'P_Pipes',
'P_RegulatorStation',
'P_Service',
'P_TownBorderStation',
'P_Valve']

#Not included inside a Dataset
in_dataset_P_EverythingElse = ['P_AbandonedDevice', 'P_AbandonedPipe',
'P_PipelineMarker']

out_dataset_P_Orwell = 'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Orwell.gdb/P_Orwell'
out_dataset_P_Integrity = 'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Orwell.gdb/P_Integrity'
out_dataset_P_PipeSystem = 'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Orwell.gdb/P_PipeSystem'
out_dataset_P_EverythingElse     
='C:/EnterpriseFolder/Orwell.gdb/P_EverythingElse'

# Execute .Exists & .Delete_management
if arcpy.Exists(out_dataset_P_Orwell):
arcpy.Delete_management(out_dataset_P_Orwell)
if arcpy.Exists(out_dataset_P_Integrity):
arcpy.Delete_management(out_dataset_P_Integrity)
if arcpy.Exists(out_dataset_P_PipeSystem):
arcpy.Delete_management(out_dataset_P_PipeSystem)
if arcpy.Exists(out_dataset_P_EverythingElse):
arcpy.Delete_management(out_dataset_P_EverythingElse)


Create_dataset_P_Orwell = 'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Orwell.gdb'
out_name_P_Orwell = "P_Orwell"

Create_dataset_P_Integrity = 'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Orwell.gdb'
out_name_P_Integrity = "P_Integrity"

Create_dataset_P_Integrity = 'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Orwell.gdb'
out_name_P_PipeSystem = "P_PipeSystem"

Create_dataset_P_Integrity = 'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Orwell.gdb'
out_name_P_EverythingElse = "P_EverythingElse"

sr = arcpy.SpatialReference("NAD 1983 UTM Zone 11N")

# Execute .CreateFeaturedataset
arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(Create_dataset_P_Orwell, out_name_P_Orwell,sr)
arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(Create_dataset_P_Integrity, out_name_P_Integrity,sr)
arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(Create_dataset_P_Integrity, out_name_P_PipeSystem,sr)
arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(Create_dataset_P_Integrity,     out_name_P_EverythingElse,sr)

arcpy.env.outputMFlag = "Disabled"
arcpy.env.outputZFlag = "Disabled"

# Execute .FeatureClassToGeodatabase
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(in_dataset_P_Orwell,     out_dataset_P_Orwell)
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(in_dataset_P_Integrity,     out_dataset_P_Integrity)
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(in_dataset_P_PipeSystem,             out_dataset_P_PipeSystem)
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(in_dataset_P_EverythingElse,         
out_dataset_P_EverythingElse)

print "Finished!"

# Open a log file to write to
#
f = open(r'C:\Orwell Schedule.log','w')

# Write date/time
#
f.write(time.strftime('%x %X'))
f.write('\n')

# Test receiving of arguments/parameters via arcpy
#
f.write("Parameter 0 : " + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + "\n")

# Python info
#
f.write("Python EXE : " + sys.executable + "\n")
f.write("Architecture : " + platform.architecture()[0] + "\n")
f.write("Path to arcpy : " + imp.find_module("arcpy")[1] + "\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: ESRI rule of thumb: remove space from the folder/file name and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed this piece of code from each workspace section and it's now working properly.

```
# Test receiving of arguments/parameters via arcpy
#
f.write("Parameter 0 : " + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + "\n")

# Python info
#
f.write("Python EXE : " + sys.executable + "\n")
f.write("Architecture : " + platform.architecture()[0] + "\n")
f.write("Path to arcpy : " + imp.find_module("arcpy")[1] + "\n")
```